# passing the value of r variable inside latex equation to display in kable

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr

I have to display output of r variable inside a latex equation inside a kable cell.
When I use the below

```
data2$Physics<-c('$\\frac{7}{20}$')
```

It displays properly inside a kable cell.
But the problem is when I want to pass an r variable, I tried the below all fails:

```
data2$Physics<-c('$\\frac{`r phy`}{20}$')

data2$Physics<-c('$\\frac{\\Sexpr{phy}{20}$')
```

Any help please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are already in an R code chunk, you don't need inline R code.  Just paste in the value:

```
data2$Physics <- paste0('$\\frac{', phy, '}{20}$')
```

If you want to control the format of `phy`, you can use `sprintf`.  For example, if `phy` is 3.141593 but you only want two decimals to show, use

```
data2$Physics <- sprintf('$\\frac{%.2f}{20}$', phy)
```

The value in `phy` is formatted according to the C-style format `%.2f` and embedded in the string.

Comment: I wasted my two days...your solution is so elegant...thanks